# Is there a term for a story without mythological / religious roots?

Tags: terminology

There is the philosophical question whether there is such thing as a story without a reference to a religious or mythological teaching.  That is a question for another SE or group.

My question is:

**Is there a *term* for a story, poem or written art that has no mythological / religious roots.**

The question is not about *whether it can exist*, but is there a phrase to describe this situation.

[background - this is for a presentation, which aims to state, 'while it seems that all stories have a connection to mythology or religion, some believe that ____ is/are an exception.']

Comment: I think that's just "story". Stories *with* allegorical elements are called "allegories". Stories shroud in the trappings of mythology are called "myths". Stories told to instill some moral truth are called "parables". And so on. And while numerologists can, post-hoc, make the case that any arbitrary event was "predicted" by their Scripture, so litcrits can, post-hoc, fabricate an argument that an arbitrary story "is" allegorical, or mythological, or what have you -- but that doesn't make it *so*.

Comment: *Allegory* does **not** mean “a reference to a religious or mythological teaching”!

Comment: I agree with @tchrist. I think the closest you'll get is *secular non-fiction*.

Comment: @Lawrence I agree with tchrist too, but I don't think tchrist's comment was aimed at me or invalidated anything I said. In other words, I'm sticking by my position that the word OP is looking for is *story* (which, to your point, if we're allowed to consider non-fiction for the the purposes of this question, then the items one finds in newspapers are also called *stories*, and it would be a hard case to make that OJ drove that white Bronco to instill some religious teaching in the public at large).

Comment: @DanBron My previous comment wasn't related to yours, just tchrist's. I took *his* comment to be about the OP's phrase *without allegory (a reference to a religious or mythological teaching)*. However, regarding *story*, I think the OP wants a term for something that is *devoid* of mythological and religious roots, not one for something that *includes* (instances of) them.

Comment: @Lawrence The complaint I have about seeking such a word is the implicit premise that such aspects are present *by default*. It's like asking for a profession *devoid* of red noses and giant shoes. Or an animal *devoid* of secret schemes for world domination. And so on. The word is "profession" or "animal" or whatever, and if you want to then pick out the subsets which *have* some specific feature, like red noses or hidden agendas, you *qualify* the word, or use the word *with* those specific meanings. Not that I'm arguing wth you, here, more I struggle with Qs founded on problematic premises.

Comment: @DanBron They sometimes exist - e.g. animals that fly and are not mammals? *Birds* comes close. :)

Comment: @Lawrence You're painting with positive space ("things which do X"), OP is trying to paint with negative space ("things that don't do X"), which sometimes works, if "not doing X" is the exception, and not the norm. Going back to my clowns example: what is the name for professions which *don't* have as part of their standard equipment both red noses and giant shoes? The question is ill-founded.

Comment: If you are determined to do so, you can find a religious or mythological element or reference in anything.  One of the ways you can do this is to say "X is a Christ figure".  OJ was on his way to Calvary (see Dan Bron's comment.)  Prove me wrong!

Comment: The only thing I'll cite as an objection to in your question is the word *allegory* - see [tchrist's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314807/is-there-a-term-for-a-story-without-allegory?noredirect=1#comment713754_314807) above. If you remove that word and the round brackets, I'm prepared to vote to reopen this question. Obviously, others have a different view, so it would be advisable to *edit your question* to address their objections at the same time. Otherwise, after reopening the question, it is likely to be voted closed again.

Comment: @Lawrence - I have edited as requested.  The emphasis is the background statement at the end of the question.  Thanks all for the clarification.  Full disclosure, this is not my rodeo; I need an umbrella term for stories that have zero connection to mythology/religion.

Comment: @Mikey Thanks for your edit and for the gracious way you've conducted yourself. I will vote to re-open in good faith. But the bottom line is I don't think you're going to find what you're looking for, for the reasons I outlined. For most of the world, stories *are not* founded, by default, on religious or mythological roots. Asking for such a term is like asking "What's the word for a dog which *does not* have brown and white spots?". It's just unlikely that anyone has coined such a term. It is much more likely that someone has coined a term for stories which *do* have religious/myth roots.

Comment: @DanBron - I'll do anything I can to try to get an answer and if it's not working, then I am fine having it removed.  However, every movie, book, story, etc. that I've ever seen, listened to or heard has had some kind of connection to things like "the underdog wins," (David & Goliath), or the meek shall inherit the Earth, etc.  I know that other stories might exist that have nothing to do with these, but I don't know what to call it.  Thank you for your help: You've improved the presentation by a magnitude of order.

Comment: @Mikey Ah, I think you maybe should consider whether, in fact, the egg came before the chicken. I don't think every underdog story in the world is derived from David and Goliath (I can *guarantee* you, for example, that tribes in the Amazon basin which didn't have contact with the outside world until the 1990s tell underdog stories), but rather than David & Goliath is just one more example of an underdog story. To want the little guy to win sometimes is part of human nature, and whether it's David and Goliath or Woody Allen, every underdog story is just an expression of that.

Comment: @DanBron - Okay, if they don't have myths, etc.  I knew this was a wider philosophical question.  What I'm searching for is merely the "term" for a story that has no roots as such (if that term exists).

Comment: @Mikey Yeah, I understand, all my comments here were just  intended to communicate to you why my strong belief is no such term exists. It would exist if more people shared your conviction that most stories are based on myth (or what have you), but I don't think that idea is very widespread. Anyway, I've cast my reopen vote, I'll be very interested in any more discussion this question generates.

Comment: @Mikey I've just checked back into ELU and saw that your question has already been opened - congratulations! I gather from your comments that you're not quite satisfied with the 2 answers given. I invite you to comment below my answer on why it isn't quite what you're after. Dan Bron may indeed be correct, but let's see if we can get closer to what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

A **personal anecdote**, being a short story about a real person, has no religious roots. The same is true of any biographical narrative, with the exception of those directly related to mythological or religious figures.

> While it seems impossible to have a story without a connection to
>   mythology or religion, some believe that personal anecdotes are an exception."

Other exceptions include portraits and landscapes in art and nonsense verse (like limericks) in poetry, to cover the other fields you mentioned.

Comment: Anecdotes can be about religious figures and their teachings.

Comment: I edited in "with the exception of those directly related to mythological or religious figures," but thinking it over, *personal* anecdote avoids that critique.

Comment: @GetzelR Of course, "all <stories/anecdotes/etc> with the exception of those related to mythological or religious figures" is the ultimate answer. But I like your illustration here that stories can just *be*, with no underlying metaphor.

Comment: @DanBron I think OP is looking for a specific genre of stories to prove his point. The premise he is challenging strikes me as absurd - all modern (post-biblical etc) non-fiction meets his criteria, as does all fiction not actually myth or "fan-fiction" set in those worlds. Fiction by definition is invented and can be said to be influenced by, but not rooted in, other fictions

Comment: I think you and I agree the premise is absurd, and we're on the same page with respect to your description of fiction. But my take-away from the question was that OP believes, and his audience believes, "*while it seems impossible to have a story without a connection to mythology or religion*", and and he wants to offer "*some believe that ____ is/are an exception*" as an /exception/.

Comment: @DanBron Right. Which is why I offer *personal anecdote*. Of course, the post-hoc crowd you mention (overzealous fans of Campbell, I'd imagine) could examine the anecdote's structure and relate it to myth or religion, bringing even the story about the time the store was out of tomatoes into the mythology/religious story tradition.

Answer (score 1):

Try *secular non-fiction* to exclude both myth (fiction) and religion.

> **Secular** *adjective*
> 1 Not connected with religious or spiritual matters
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/secular)
>
> **Non-fiction** *noun*
> Prose writing that is informative or factual rather than fictional
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/non-fiction)

Your sample sentence is then

> While it seems impossible to have a story without a connection to mythology or religion, some believe that secular non-fiction is an exception.

You have taken pains to separate the philosophical discussion from the English phrase request. The discussions on this page have led to the philosophical position that stories that are merely *motivated* by religious themes, such as your example of the triumphant underdog, are to be labelled religious; and stories that could be given a religious interpretation even after they have been written are also to be labelled religious. By definition, then, those stories are *not* secular.

> The question is not about whether it can exist, but is there a phrase to describe this situation.

This answer is compatible with the notion that although philosophically there may be no such thing as *secular non-fiction*, that's what it would be called if it existed. That is, although I offer a name for the category (the English *phrase to describe this situation*), I don't claim that any story exists within that category (cf *The question is not about whether it can exist*).

Comment: Hi Lawrence, +1 for non-fiction & secular, but I am looking for an umbrella term for written word that expressly has no ties to religion/mythology.  So there may be a secular story, for example, where a guy rights a wrong - having no interest in religion, but it is still inherently based off of religious morals.

Philosophically, I might have to accept that there is not such a thing.

Comment: In this context, it's by definition not *secular* if it has a religious basis.

Comment: @Lawrence If you read [Mikey's comment just before the Q was re-opened](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314807/is-there-a-term-for-a-story-without-mythological-religious-roots#comment714517_314807), you'll see that his position is that underdog stories have their basis in David & Goliath. This holds even for secular films - *Rocky*, say, or *The Karate Kid* - because while their authors may have not *intentionally* based their works on religious or mythical themes, they are rooted in them nonetheless. I imagine similar doubts extend to non-fiction, as well.

Comment: @DanBron I understand what you're saying - by Mikey's definition, *all* literature is touched by religion, either intrinsically (e.g. Rocky) or by *post hoc* interpretation, *a la* [ab2](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/121061/ab2). I'm inclined to agree. But that is a position rooted in philosophy, which Mikey explicitly keeps out of bounds for this question (see penultimate paragraph of his question). My answer is that the English "phrase to describe this situation" is *secular non-fiction*. (cont'd ...)

Comment: @DanBron We're fast concluding that there's no such thing, and that's fine with the OP and me. :) That is, I'm fine with the notion that *there's no such thing as "secular non-fiction", but if there were, that's what it would be called*.